# Regex Gone Wild

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using the Kaggle Titanic challenge dataset to extract titles from names using the re import. I get a title match about 80% - 90% of the time. The 10% to 20% of the time it returns a title that is not in the name.

I have tried changing the pattern from ' (\S).' to ' ([a-zA-Z]).'

```
import re
combinedSet['Title'] = ''
for index, t in combinedSet.iterrows():
    # title_string = re.search(' (\S+)\.', t.Name).group(1)
    title_string = re.search(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', t.Name).group(1)
    combinedSet.loc[index, 'Title'] = title_string
    title_string = ""
```

If it cannot match I would expect a null return, but it is returning the correct title from the Name column in Pandas some of the time. The fact that a Miss jumps to a Mr or a Mrs is confusing. The dataframe if very clean following the pattern of

A sample name from the dataset is Todoroff, Mr. Lalio

Trying the regex pattern with my regex works as expected.

I am wondering if this a Pandas memory issue.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the Dataframe, especially the rows where your code does not return the match?

Comment: Can you add some data so that we can help? Also, you don't have to clear the title_string variable at the end of the loop.

Comment: After getting PyCharm to recognize my Anaconda environment and develop a code, I discovered that the problem exists in the Jupyter Notebook, not Python.

Comment: After getting PyCharm to recognize my Anaconda environment and develop a code, I discovered that the problem exists in the Jupyter Notebook, not Python. The dataset is from the Kaggle Titanic challenge.

import pandas as pd
import re

fileName = "/titanic/data/train.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    title_string = re.search(' (\S+)\.', row.Name).group(1)
    if str(row.Name).find(title_string):
        print(index, row.Name, row.Sex, title_string)

I can't replicate the random titles using PyCharm.

Comment: I was tweaking my data model and found myself, again, wanting to iterrows. My transformation works fine for about 700 rows and then goes wild. Reading the Pandas docs [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html] note 2 warns against modifying content. It would seem that the developers are warning against modifying results. Apply works like a champ on large datasets.